# How to fix a compilation error of "terra" package in RStudio?

Tags: r, compilation, terra

Installation attempts of the R package "terra" continuously end up with a persisting compilation error (Fatal error: cannot open file '../tools/winlibs.R': No such file or directory).

**Console**

```
R version 4.0.1 (2020-06-06) -- "See Things Now"
Copyright (C) 2020 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)

> library(Rcpp)
> remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")
Downloading GitHub repo rspatial/terra@HEAD
-- R CMD build ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
v  checking for file 'C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Temp\Rtmp2tVCLq\remotes43fc7a481e9\rspatial-terra-9494a5e/DESCRIPTION' ...
-  preparing 'terra': (3.1s)
v  checking DESCRIPTION meta-information ... 
-  cleaning src
-  checking for LF line-endings in source and make files and shell scripts (690ms)
-  checking for empty or unneeded directories (372ms)
-  building 'terra_1.7-59.tar.gz'
   Warnung: file 'terra/cleanup' did not have execute permissions: corrected
   Warnung: file 'terra/configure' did not have execute permissions: corrected
   
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/XXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package 'terra' ...
** using staged installation

   **********************************************
   WARNING: this package has a configure script
         It probably needs manual configuration
   **********************************************


** libs
rm -f terra.dll RcppExports.o RcppFunctions.o RcppModule.o arith.o crs.o distRaster.o distance.o extract.o file_utils.o focal.o gcp.o gdal_algs.o gdal_multidimensional.o gdalio.o geodesic.o geos_methods.o geosphere.o math_utils.o mediancut.o memory.o movingWindow.o ncdf.o ram.o raster_methods.o raster_stats.o rasterize.o read.o read_gdal.o read_ogr.o sample.o sort.o spatBase.o spatDataframe.o spatFactor.o spatRaster.o spatRasterMultiple.o spatSources.o spatTime.o spatVector.o spatVector2.o string_utils.o vecmath.o vecmathse.o vector_methods.o write.o write_gdal.o write_ogr.o
mkdir -p ../inst
"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-40~1.1/bin/x64/Rscript.exe" --vanilla "../tools/winlibs.R" 3.4.1
Fataler Fehler: kann Datei '../tools/winlibs.R' nicht öffnen: No such file or directory

make: *** [Makevars.win:27: winlibs] Error 2
ERROR: compilation failed for package 'terra'
* removing 'C:/Users/XXXXX/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/terra'
Warnmeldung:
In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/XXXXX/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2tVCLq/file43fc3a0e5fe4/terra_1.7-59.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
>
```

Re-installing Rtools has already been tried.

Comment: You don't seem to own where you are installing, hence the permission warnings above, that say corrected - but weren't actually. Can't say more that I can test as on linux, my experience is `terra` doesn't care/test for ownership, whereas with `sf` I always have to install as admin. So, switch to admin as try.

Comment: I have already tried to run RStudio as admin. The error still persisted.

Comment: [Install Steps](https://rspatial.r-universe.dev/terra#), you've done install Rcpp, you want to do `Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")` in console, then `remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")`, hopefully that fixes (sorry, don't use RStudio either).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the exact same problem, I resolved it by installing the newest version of R (R4.3.2) and then trying it again and it worked. I also had to install the package "Rcpp" and Rtools43. you can find how to install Rtools43 here:https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/Rtools/rtools43/rtools.html

```
install.packages("Rcpp")
```

then I could install the package "terra" without any problems as suggested on GitHub (https://github.com/rspatial/terra).

```
Sys.setenv("R_REMOTES_NO_ERRORS_FROM_WARNINGS" = "true")
remotes::install_github("rspatial/terra")
```

I did all of that in the Rgui and not RStudio because it didn't work there.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to install the released version of "terra" is

```
install.packages("terra")
```

And the development version can be installed like this:

```
install.packages('terra', repos='https://rspatial.r-universe.dev')
```

Using `install_github` is more complicated. And you probably do not need that (you provide no reason). But see the [instructions](https://github.com/rspatial/terra) if you do.